# How to set material ui datagrid column sort icon as always be visible?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/datagrid-demo-tnugu?file=/demo.js). I am trying to have the ability to sort by the first name and last name The default Datagrid only shows the sort icon when hovering. Is there a way I can set it to be always visible?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did:

```
const StyledDataGrid = styled(DataGrid)(() => ({
  '& .MuiDataGrid-iconButtonContainer': {
    marginLeft: '2px',
    visibility: 'visible !important',
    width: 'auto !important',
  },
}))
```

I created a styled component which adds some custom styling to DataGrid. Specifically to always show the icon and take up width for it. Using *!important* is not recommended, but doesn't harm in this case.

I must add, this only works with using custom sort icons, like so:

```
<StyledDataGrid
  components={{
    ColumnSortedAscendingIcon,
    ColumnSortedDescendingIcon,
    ColumnUnsortedIcon,
  }}
/>
```

If you don't want to use custom icons, I'm sure it's doable, you just need to play with CSS bit more.

Comment: Used the styling provided in the other comment:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75239263/6030239

Answer (score 3):

You can use the sx prop in DataGrid like so:

```
  <DataGrid
    sx={{
      '.MuiDataGrid-iconButtonContainer': {
        visibility: 'visible',
      },
      '.MuiDataGrid-sortIcon': {
        opacity: 'inherit !important',
      },
    }}
```

In my case, I had to style both the `iconButtonContainer` and `sortIcon` make sure it's always visible.

Answer (score 2):

you can use .MuiDataGrid-iconButtonContainer. however Material-UI doesn't provided default icon for unsorted list. I have forked your demo and updated it. added icon for unsorted list too. please check [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/datagrid-demo-forked-kwvrg)

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in .scss file. (.MuiDataGrid-sortIcon is pre-defined class of Mui Datagrid). Hope it helps!

```
.MuiDataGrid-sortIcon {
 opacity: inherit !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, ( used styled-components library for styles )

```js
const StyledDataGrid = styled(DataGrid)((theme) => ({
    "& .MuiDataGrid-sortIcon": {
        opacity: 'inherit !important',
      },
      
    "& .MuiDataGrid-iconButtonContainer": {
        visibility: 'visible',
    }
    }));
```

and then used it in the code accordingly

```js
 < StyledDataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} />
```

hope it helps.